# Displaying a button on top of thumbnail image

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm trying to place a button on top of a thumbnail image but the button is added after the image, in the caption area. 
Here is the code:

```
<div class="thumbnail">
    <img class="img-responsive"alt="300x200" src="network_sec.jpg">
    <button class="btn btn-default btn-warning pull-right"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span> 10</button>

    <div class="caption">
        <h3 align="center">Network Security</h3>
        <br>
        <p>
        <button class="btn btn-default btn-danger"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-wrench"></span> Manage</button>
           <button class="btn btn-default btn-danger"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-eye-open"></span> Preview</button>
            <button class="btn btn-default btn-danger"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span> Edit Info</button>
        </p>   
    </div>
</div>
```

I'm trying to align the button at the bottom right part of the image. Any suggestions on how can I achieve the desired result?

Comment: use position absolute for the button and position relative for the thumbnail and the thumbnail & button container

Comment: try this -<button class="btn btn-default btn-warning pull-right" style="position: absolute; margin-left: -5px; margin-top: 30px;">

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would put the image an the button in a new div, then use positioning relative and absolute like this.

HTML

```
<div class="thumbnail">
    <div id="thumb">
    <img class="img-responsive"alt="300x200" src="network_sec.jpg">
    <button class="btn btn-default btn-warning pull-right"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span> 10</button>
     </div>  
    <div class="caption">
    <h3 align="center">Network Security</h3>
    <br>
   <p>

    <button class="btn btn-default btn-danger"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-wrench"></span> Manage</button>
    <button class="btn btn-default btn-danger"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-eye-open"></span> Preview</button>
    <button class="btn btn-default btn-danger"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span> Edit Info</button>
 </p>   

</div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#thumb
{
    position: relative;
    width: 300px;
    height: 200px;
}

#thumb img
{
    z-index: 1;
    position: absolute;  
    width: 300px;
    height:200px;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;

}
#thumb button
{
    z-index: 5;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
}
```

Is that what you had in mind?

Comment: Yes, the positioning of the button is what I wanted but it has resized the whole image now. I'd like the image to stay it's original size.

Comment: I wasn't sure what size the image was based on your html, but I saw 200x300 so guessed it was that.  You can change the widths and heights on both the thumb and img styles.

Comment: Right but the image no longer remains responsive with custom height and width. How do I solve this problem?

Comment: can you use percentages? or max-width and max-height properties?

Comment: Setting width to auto helps but height is still giving me a problem. If I set the height to auto, the whole image disappears

Comment: if you set either height or width on the to auto, and then the other value (which ever you did not set to auto) as something like, max-width(or height): 100px(or something); then does the img not resize itself down if the browser shrinks?

Comment: Ok, it works. The dimensions of the image were causing problems.
Thanks alot! :)